# why not using constructor when making subclass of list class?

Tags: python, constructor, built-in-types

Here is an example.

```
>>> class MyList(list):
>>>    def __sub__(self, other):
>>>        L = self[:]
>>>        for x in other:
>>>            if x in L: L.remove(x)
>>>        return L

>>> L = MyList([1, 2, 3, 'spam', 4, 5])
>>> L = L - ['spam']
>>> print L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When class takes arguments, it requires **init**, constructors to get. 
But there is no **init** method above. How could it be possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: He's deleting from `L` while iterating over `other`; that should be OK.  (A list comprehension might be more efficient here though: `return [x for x in L if x not in other]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subclass, you inherit the methods of the parent class unless you override them in the subclass definition. So, your code is using the __init__() function of the base list class.